# React Native : ADB Issue for create-react-native-app

Tags: android, react-native, adb, create-react-app

Error running adb: Failed to install C:\Users\Username.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.0.0.apk: Error: must either specify a package size or an APK file

This is my error. I have Andriod emulator running and it on API 25. Java 1.8

Could anyone help me on this? I have react-native init and run-android running properly. But not create-reactive-native-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the expo apk is not downloaded fully and it's trying to install a corrupt apk. Couple of ways to fix this.

- Delete the .expo/android-apk-cache folder in your home folder and retry
- Manually download and install the expo apk https://expo.io/tools (lower right corner)

Comment: Thanks Peter. This works..Also  if anyone doesnt know how to install Expo in Emulator, try command 'adb install path/to/expo.apk' (you can search and download from net, search ""expo for pc"" ,http://downloadapk.net/LRA-EXPO.html).. Thanks to @Peter Lazar for sharing this information.